# How to login using request type post.?

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

I need to login with email and password using post method. For this i add this part of code on login button, please look at this.

```
 if (_email.text.length >0 ) {
    if (_password.text.length >0) {
        Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
        if (status) {
            [SVProgressHUD setOffsetFromCenter:UIOffsetMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 60)];


            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"loading.." ];
            NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&deviceToken=testdata",_email.text,self.password.text];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[urlString length]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
            NSString *url = @"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/users/app/login";
            [req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [req setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [req setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:
             ^(NSURLResponse *reponse , NSData *data, NSError *error){
                 NSError *errre1;
                 diclogin=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&errre1];
                 NSLog(@"result is%@ :",diclogin);
                 [user setObject:[diclogin objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];

                 NSLog(@"user %@", user);

                 if ([diclogin objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                     [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                     ViewController *secondViewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Map"];
                     [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
                 }else {
                     [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                     loginalerview.tag = 1;
                     loginalerview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SignIn !" message:[diclogin objectForKey:@"msg"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                     loginalerview.tag = 1;

                     [loginalerview show];
                 }

             }];
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Alert" message:@"Please check your internet." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        }
    }else{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Alert !" message:@"Please enter the password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}else{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Alert !" message:@"Please enter email." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    _password.text = @"";
}
```

But when i print user in console i get null value. i entered correct credentials. This block is not compile right now.

```
if ([dictLogin objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                         [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                         ViewController *secondViewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Map"];
                     [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

                        }
```

Comment: Please help someone i am stuck here from last few days

Comment: Check the "completion:nil];" statement after the push on the nav controller, this is what causes the compilation error.

Comment: please look at updated question, that line was added by mistake'

Comment: i want to know why this block not executed  if ([diclogin objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                         NSLog(@"hello");
                         [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                         ViewController *secondViewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Map"];
                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
                     }

Comment: Please post also the response you get from the server.

Comment: 2016-04-27 13:26:55.518 Juststart[4534:114792] urlstring &email=a@b.c&password=qwert&deviceToken=testdata
2016-04-27 13:26:56.328 Juststart[4534:114792] result is{
    acType = "";
    code = 400;
    message = "Oops! Wrong password.";
    status = 0;
    user = "<null>";
} :
2016-04-27 13:26:56.329 Juststart[4534:114792] user (null)

Comment: Well, the response is clear enough. You're sending a wrong password to the server. The code is never executed because the response doesn't have an object under the "email" key so the if fails.

Comment: sir i entered correct password, everyone  else use the same credentials

Comment: is there any way to send data after making objects of email and password?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't know anything about your project and I'm basing my comments on what I see. The server response says "Oops! Wrong password" so I'm guessing that this is your problem.

Comment: ok sir no problem thanks for your support